# Creating Two Threads by passing the same instance of Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading

```
Thread runnableInst = new Runnable(){  public void run(){}};

Thread thread1 = new Thread(runnableInst);
Thread thread2 = new Thread(runnableInst);

thread1.start();
thread2.start();
```

Is it fine to start two thread on the same Object runnableInst ?

Is it good to make this kind of design?

Comment: `Thread runnableInst = new Runnable(){  public void run(){}};` Thread is already a `Runnable`. This is confusing code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this but one thing to watch is that both threads will be accessing the instance data of the `runnableInst`. So you will have to make sure that access is synchronised where necessary.

Comment: If the variables are strictly local variables the method, this shouldn't affect the other threads.  Each one should have their own method stack and thus their own variables.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with doing that. However, if you plan on dispatching a lot of parallel tasks, you might want to start using the `ExecutorService` API.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible. I don't think it is fine or good design in most situations. I like to consider a Runnable instance to be an isolated piece of code that only shares data with other threads through well-defined, safe ways.

Comment: Can you add some more insight on it or if possible please share some link.

Comment: It's a big topic. If you are interested in Java concurrency, then you should read Java Concurrency in Practice. It's _the_ book for this field

Answer (score 0):

Is it fine to start two thread on the same Object runnableInst ?

Yes, it is fine to start two threads on the same Object runnableInst.

Is it good to make this kind of design -- it depends on the use case. For example, if there is nothing related to a read/write on a shared resource, then this is a good design.